# How to deploy standalone EJB 3 modules on JBoss with dependencies between them?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, jboss6.x

I have a Java EE application developed in this structure:

Application1.ear
  - Application1.war
Application1DAO.jar (EJB standalone module)
Application1Business.jar  (EJB standalone module)
Application1Facade.jar  (EJB standalone module)

Application2.ear
  - Application2DAO.jar  (EJB module)
  - Application2Business.jar  (EJB module)
  - Application2Web.war

So, the application was divided in this way to achieve business rules.

The Application1 EJB modules (DAO, Business and Facade) are deployed as standalone modules because Application2 use these EJBs too.

Well, to achieve this in a Glassfish 3.1 Server, for all of these EJB modules I've separated the Local and Remote interfaces into API jars and put them into domain/lib folder.

Now I have to do the same thing in a JBoss 6.0.0 Server. So, I've tried to put the API jars (Local and Remote interfaces) into server/default/lib but when I've tried to deploy Application1Business.jar, which has dependencies on Application1DAO.jar, the server throw an exception. Follow the stacktrace:

```
14:44:32,779 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///opt/javatools/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/ePublicBusiness.jar state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.UnidadeCentroCustoBusiness
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference: [EJB Reference: beanInterface 'br.com.prescon.epublic.dao.UnidadeCentroCustoDAORemote', beanName 'null', mappedName 'null', lookupName 'null', owning unit 'ComponentDeploymentContext@322802193{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.UnidadeCentroCustoBusiness}'] for environment entry: env/br.com.prescon.epublic.business.UnidadeCentroCustoBusiness/unidadeCentroCustoDAO in unit ComponentDeploymentContext@322802193{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.UnidadeCentroCustoBusiness}
at org.jboss.ejb3.jndi.deployers.resource.provider.AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.provide(AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.java:99) [:0.1.7]
at org.jboss.ejb3.jndi.deployers.resource.provider.AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.provide(AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.java:50) [:0.1.7]
at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.JndiEnvironmentProcessor.process(JndiEnvironmentProcessor.java:68) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.process(AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.java:119) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.EJBEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.internalDeploy(EJBEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.java:87) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
```

So, my question is how can I achieve the same deploy structure that I have in Glassfish using JBoss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Injection via the `@EJB` annotation doesn't work across EAR-borders (in JBoss 6).

The way to get around this is by using

> @EJB(mappedName = "JNDI name of bean")

JBoss 6 still uses non-standardized JNDI names for the beans. But these names should show up in the log when you deploy `Application1.ear`. Use the name exactly as shown including the `/remote` part at the end.